# In OpenCV, what is the svm.predect parameter returnDFVal mean

Tags: opencv

The opencv document said *"If true and the problem is 2-class classification then the method returns the decision function value that is **signed** distance to the margin"*

Is this mean that if the sample belong to the class, it will return positive number. Otherwise return a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  have wrote a test project to test the return value mean( returnDFVAL = true),  I found that the return value is the distance of the test sample to the margin.

In 2-class, you have 2 label(i.e. 1, -1).

If the test sample belong to smaller label(-1). The distance is plus.

Else if the test sample belong to the bigger label(1) , The distance is minus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I don't know what is the MAXIMUM limit (the range) of Decision Function!

I have 2-class problem [-1,1] where the feature value are in range [0,1].
When i predict the class with OpenCV, using a test-set, i got various values (in abs) for example: 0.22 ,.., 1.75,..,3.75 (i don't know the absolute maximum value in decision function scale,but only the relative 3.75).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually there is no maximum distance in decision. The bigger distance, the better reliability。 And now I use libsvm instead of opencv. I think the libsvm is more clear and easy to use